# How can I get x and y value in axis coordinates instead of matrix position?

Tags: matlab, matrix, coordinates

I need to find x and y coordinates of binary image. Here is the example picture for the code (square shape) 
     [image: fig1]
    [image: fig2]
    [image: fig3]

```
And use the codes as below:


 a=imread('square.png');
 b=im2bw(a);
 figure(1)
 imshow(b) %%show image in normal axis
 sz=size(b);
 RI=imref2d(size(b));

 xmin=-sz(2)/2;
 xmax=sz(2)/2;
 ymin=-sz(1)/2;
 ymax=sz(1)/2;
 RI.XWorldLimits=[xmin xmax];
 RI.YWorldLimits=[ymin ymax];
 figure(2) %%show image is desired axes where zero is centered of axes
 imshow(b,RI);
 [x,y]=find(b==0); 
 figure(3)
 scatter(x,y)
```

Figure(1) is original image. Figure(2) is the same image, but shown in different axis (i.e. zero is centered in x and y axes). Then I look for x and y coordinates of interested area (in this example, square frame). But the x and y coordinates that I get are not consistent with axis from figure(2). According to figure(2), x and y coordinates of square shape should be both -ve value and +ve value. But all x and y coordinates are in +ve values. I look what's the problem and then I noted that x and y values from `[x,y]=find(b==0)`are consistent with their positions in a matrix, not the axes coordinates. So, what shall i do if I want to show x and y in axes coordinates? Tks.

Comment: The outputs of `find` are going to be `[row, column]` i.e. `[y,x]` *not* `[x,y]`

Comment: hi @Suever, I have tried as you suggested. I change the code as '[y,x]=find(b==0)' but it i think it still showed x and y values as matrix positions, but not the axes coordinates. Do i miss anything? Thanks ahead.

Comment: @Teddy Also be sure to call `axis image` for all axes to ensure that the y direction is consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have the outputs of `find` reversed. It returns the rows and columns *not* `x` and `y` as you have written. So you should actually specify the outputs to be `[y,x]`.

```
[y,x] = find(b == 0);
```

Then you also want to make sure that your y direction of the scatter plot axes is flipped (using `axis image`) because this is what `imshow` (your other figures) uses by default.

```
scatter(x,y)
axis image
```

**Update**

If you want to transform these coordinates to the centered coordinates you've shown, you'll need to apply the same transform to `x` and `y` prior to calling scatter.

```
x = x + xmin;
y = y + ymin;

scatter(x,y)
```

Comment: hi @Suever. Thanks a lot for your kind advice. I have added more figures in my original post so it will be more clear. In fig 2, x and y axes have zero value in the center and it has +ve and -ve values. But in fig 3, the axes are not "zero centered", but all +ve value axes. I want fig 3 to be shown as fig2 axes. Hope it is more clearer what I want. Tks again.

Comment: @Teddy I have updated my answer. You have to apply the `xmin` and `ymin` transform to your `x` and `y` vectors.